# Interpreting the Distribution Bernoilli$(p)-p$

Tags: probability-distributions, soft-question, transformation

What is meant by $X\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)-p$?

This cannot mean that the pdf of $X$ is $f-p$, where $$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            p & \quad x =1 \\
            1-p & \quad x = 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$ is the pdf of the Bernoulli distribution since $1-2p$ can be negative.

**Excerpt:** (From page numbered 25 of http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~reinert/talks/steinintroduction.pdf)
If $X\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)-p$, then $$\mathbb{E}\lbrace XI(X>x)\rbrace=p(1-p)$$ for $-p<x<1-p$ and is zero elsewhere (where $I$ is the indicator function).

Comment: It looks like a sloppy, lazy way of writing "$X-p, X\sim\text{Bern}(p)$". But that is my first impression anyway. Do you have a source or some other context?

Comment: Page numbered 25 of http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~reinert/talks/steinintroduction.pdf

Comment: Nope, the link didn't work for me. Anyway, please include an excerpt from the document in the post for others to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bernoulli($p$) yields 1 with probability $p$ and 0 with probability $1-p$.

Bernouilli($p$)$-p$ yields $1-p$ with probability $p$ and $-p$ with probability $1-p$. So in other word $X+p \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$.

So then,
\begin{equation}
E[X I_{\{X>x\}}] = (1-p)\times P(X=1-p) + 0 \times P(X=-p) = p(1-p)
\end{equation} 
for $-p<x<1-p$.

This follows because $X I_{\{X>x\}}$ is $1-p$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$